# How does the Matching Braces extension example in Visual Studio work?

Tags: c#, mef, visual-studio-extensions

I'm going through the "[Displaying Matching Braces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee197650.aspx)" extension example on Visual Studio and need a bit of help understanding the code.

After the initial "BraceMatchingTagger" is created, for every caret movement, the "UpdateAtCaretPosition" function is called. This function is raising a TagsChanged event. I follow till here. However,

1) Who is handling this event?

2) Who calls GetTags?

My understanding is that when the caret is moved, a "TagsChanged" event is raised. The editor somehow handles this. At a later time, the extension's "GetTags" is called by the editor. Is this right? I'm also not completely clear on the order in which these functions are called.

Can someone help with these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. TagsChanged is handled by Visual Studio and it calls GetTags after UpdateAtCaretPosition returns. The call sequence is this (created using [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/)):

```
   void BraceMatchingTagger.CaretPositionChanged(CaretElement{_blinkInterval=530, _newOpacity=1., _preferredXCoordinate=2., _preferredYOffset=88., _displayedHeight=15., _displayedWidth=1., _updateNeeded=false, _isClosed=false, _emptySelection=true, _isHidden=false, _forceVirtualSpace=false, _caretGeometryNeedsToBeUpdated=true, _isContainedByView=true, _overwriteMode=false}, CaretPositionChangedEventArgs)
     void BraceMatchingTagger.UpdateAtCaretPosition(CaretPosition)
   . BraceMatchingTagger.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection)
   . <GetTags>d__20.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.ITagSpan<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.TextMarkerTag>>.GetEnumerator()
   true <GetTags>d__20.MoveNext()
     true BraceMatchingTagger.FindMatchingCloseChar(SnapshotPoint{position=27}, {, }, 7, .)
   . <GetTags>d__20.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.ITagSpan<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.TextMarkerTag>>.get_Current()
   true...false <GetTags>d__20.MoveNext()
   void <GetTags>d__20.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
```